# How to use regular expression in Google Dataflow streaming templates?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

Using the Dataflow streaming templates, namely the Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery (Stream) template, it used to be possible to describe the "inputFilePattern" (i.e.: the Cloud Storage location of the text you'd like to process) as a regular expression. For example you could enter gs://my-bucket/my-files/file-to-upload* as the parameter and all the files starting with "file-to-upload" would then be streamed.

Unfortunately it now throws this error message: "Object not found."

Is there another way to upload all files from a google storage location with a similar naming convention to BigQuery?

Please see screenshots below:

[image: Job Parameters]

[image: Bucket data location]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The template still supports matching file patterns. Can you share a screen shot of your bucket and folders as well as the parameters you are using to submit the job

Comment: Hello Jayadeep. Please see my edit above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the UI you can pass the file pattern when you submit the job via command line. The source code takes the file pattern as input so there should not be any problem with the actual job

```
    PCollectionTuple transformedOutput =
        pipeline

            // 1) Read from the text source continuously.
            .apply(
                "ReadFromSource",
                TextIO.read()
                    .from(options.getInputFilePattern())
                    .watchForNewFiles(DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL, Growth.never()))
```

Comment: Jayadeep is correct. The GCS location picker does not yet support regex validation.